# Error while starting the backend in the node app.js in angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

When I am starting my backend in the angular using the node app.js command in the terminal it shows some error

I tried all the methods like `npm-install` or `npm-install --save`

> ```
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.7
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /nodemon/chokidar/fsevents:
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.7
> npm WARN mongoose-type-url@1.0.5 requires a peer of mongoose@ but none was installed.
> npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-44-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
> npm ERR! node v8.10.0
> npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
> npm ERR! file /home/suraj/contactly/sales-tool/salesapp/node_modules/.staging/encrypt-36282e46/package.json
> npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
>
> npm ERR! Failed to parse json
> npm ERR! Unexpected token 'n' at 1:3
> npm ERR! { name: 'encrypt',
> npm ERR!   ^
> npm ERR! File: /home/suraj/contactly/sales-tool/salesapp/node_modules/.staging/encrypt-36282e46/package.json
> npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
> npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
> npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /home/suraj/contactly/sales-tool/salesapp/npm-debug.log
> ```

want to fix the bug

Comment: Did you read the error message? `package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript`

Comment: Delete the node_modules in sales-tool. Go into /home/suraj/contactly/sales-tool/salesapp and "npm install" them from scratch.